# Size and position of shapes on different computers VBA EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba

I have just encountered a problem with shapes positioning in excel via VBA on different machines with different screen resolutions.

Using my code I want to make width of the shape corresponding to the days. Of course prior that I made width of columns to fix value, than I measured width of one object corresponded to one year and tried to find width of one day.

```
relZeroXalt = Application.CentimetersToPoints(2.7)
oneDayAlt = Application.CentimetersToPoints(6.38 / 365)

macros.Sheets("Network").Activate
macros.Sheets("Network").Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, relZeroXalt + start * oneDayAlt, relZeroY + delta + (padLevel - 1) * height + space * padLevel, oneDayAlt * days, height).Select
```

It worked on my machine, all widths for all objects were correctly calculated, but on different machine it doesn't get for the right dates..

Do any of you know what could be a problem?

Comment: Can you share more code / context to explain how you calulated the other parameters in `.Shapes.AddShape`, please?

Comment: @nicolaus-hee I don't think they are relevant to this as they are constants. Main accent is to width parameter which comes from input file (for ex. first object should be 10days width, and 365 width is 10cm in excel, than I convert it to points from cm and than divide by 365). The problem is that in my pc one year is 10cm, but on others could be more or less, depends on something I don't understand yet

Comment: Those depend on display scaling (set in display settings) and `Application.ActiveWindow.Zoom` of the worksheet (slider at the bottom right corner). <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch>, <https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/dpi-and-device-independent-pixels>, <https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/glossary/vbe-glossary#twip>